# Python Abstract Syntax: Detect syntax error's'

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to detect multiple python syntax errors with one iteration?

Python file with 2 syntax errors **test.py**:

```
print 'hello'
test =-
b = 1 + 1
test =+
print 'world'
```

This code only gets to the first syntax error on line 2, not to the error on line 4:

```
import parser
parser.suite(open('test.py').read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2
    test =-
```

**How could I detect *all* syntax errors of a *.py file?** (not only the first)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot, because after one syntax error the rest of the code structure is no longer recoverable.

Take a missing parenthesis for example; was that a parenthesis that was missing, or a comma? Is the function call on the next line therefor part of the expression with the error, or not? If the comma was missing, there might be a parenthesis missing on the next line. If the parenthesis was missing, there might be a parenthesis too many on the next line. That'd be two  very different syntax errors that *depend* on what the previous syntax error really was meant to be.

A syntax error in one place invalidates the rest of the code and there is no point in continuing parsing, at least not for Python which needs to produce valid bytecode.

You can use a [Python linter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611776/what-are-the-comprehensive-lint-checkers-for-python); many can be integrated with your text editor of choice. A Python IDE or linter does not have to produce bytecode and can be more flexible in handling syntax errors (continueing checking on subsequent lines), and can tell you about other problems too, like missing or unused imports and variables.

Comment: How could a python IDE check the syntax of the whole file then?
@function call: not it is not part of the expression .. "somebody" messed the py-file in this fictional example

Comment: @asonico: Guesses can be made on a line-by-line basis, but fixing one syntax error earlier on might make the rest of the code suddenly valid. Or all invalid. An IDE has the luxury of being able to re-evaluate the code on the fly as you edit though.

Comment: so an IDE would do a few Syntax checks to achieve good results:

* checking the whole context
* check every line alone for syntax
* check indents


Am I right?

Comment: Yes, IDEs generally do their own parsing and as they don't need to produce an actual compilation, their options are more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You may get several problems flagged by a run through [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) or [pychecker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyChecker) **but** correcting any one of them may have a big effect on later ones - **BTW** running one or both on your code regularly is ***highly*** recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pyflakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes/):

```
sudo pip install pyflakes
```

My test.py has simply:

```
a
a
```

pychecker test.py output:

```
test.py:1: undefined name 'a'
test.py:2: undefined name 'a'
```

I give no guarantee this is perfect.  It could mess up like C/C++ does and keep throwing false errors, but the same is true of any tool.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
'+func(1,2
```

There might be just one syntax errror:

```
'+func(1,2'
```

or there could be 2 syntax errors: both a parethesis and a quotation mark:

```
''+func(1,2)
```

Since there are so many ways to fix SyntaxErrors, there is no canonical way to indentify all SyntaxErrors.